# Is it legal to update cursor's querying table in the loop of fetching data from it

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

For example , is it ok to do below ?

```
DECLARE aId VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT  id FROM new_records WHERE is_loaded = false;
read_loop: LOOP

    FETCH cur1 INTO aId;
    ...
    update new_records set is_loaded = True where id = aId ; 
    ...
    CLOSE cur1;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursors in MySQL are ASENSITIVE ([13.6.6 Cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursors.html)).

> An INSENSITIVE Cursor is a Cursor that effectively causes a separate
>   copy of its result Table to be created; the Cursor accesses that copy,
>   rather than the original result, so any changes made to the original
>   result by other methods won't be visible to this Cursor. A SENSITIVE
>   Cursor is a Cursor that works directly on its result Table: it makes
>   no copy, so other changes made to the result Table will be visible to
>   this Cursor. An ASENSITIVE Cursor may or may not make a copy of its
>   result Table; whether other changes to its result Table will be
>   visible is implementation-defined. The default is an ASENSITIVE
>   Cursor.

*- From [DECLARE CURSOR Statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/declare-cursor-statement/) -*

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340a4/1)</kbd>

However, depending on what you need to do, there are other ways to update the table.

Comment: thanks , and , by other ways, do you means using temp tables ?